# What's the limit of chrome-dev source file?

Tags: javascript, php, drupal-7, google-chrome-devtools

Ok, so let me explain the question

I have the following code on my Drupal module (PHP)

```
switch (granularity) {
    case 'day':
      $fromdate = date('2016-02-01');
      $todate = date('2016-02-29'); //<--------------------
      $requesttype = "Hourly";
      break;

$result = get_api_call($requesttype,$fromdate,$todate);
dpm($result);
$items['my_module_name']['#items']['data'] = $result;
```

And to pass it to JS, i simply do an echo a let JS do it's magic

```
var data = <?php print json_encode($variables['items']['data']); ?>;
```

So... on this API call i'm getting one month times 24 hours each day, times two data on each hour of the day = (31*24*2 = 1488)

If i try to echo all this into the `<scirpt>` tag inside a .tpl
The js file doesn´t load on the sources tab, hence i can't debug...
[image]
The funny thing is that if i reduce the API call to less days like, like 15
The chrome-dev tool does show/load the JS I can debug
[image: It works with 15 days]

So... What's happening? Because I've seen ginormous JS files/librarys load into chrome dev-tools

Maybe an object broken, maybe json_encode isn't working with a ginormous array?
Any clue?

PS: Even if it doesn't show the JS file it still runs and works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the source code for Chrome Dev Tools and I couldn't find any limit for line/character length or size in the Sources panel. Therefore, I'd say there's probably no hard limit.

There is also no limit to the `json_encode` function. It is only limited by the amount of memory you have. Since you say the JS file runs correctly, there must have been enough memory on the server to encode the data.

In your screenshots, there are some errors shown. Check the Console tab, as it may shine a light. I suspect you have run into a memory issue in Dev Tools.

For large amounts of data, it may be worth looking into AJAX for requesting more data instead of sending all of it at once to the client.

Comment: Nah, the errors on the console are something else, plus they're also there in the smaller request where it does show the JS code.